# How to install javascript package via Github

Tags: javascript, html, github, npm, installation

I'm still learning javascript but Im getting better at it every day. Now I would like to install a package and run it on my pc. For example this one: https://www.jqueryscript.net/chart-graph/Fully-Customizable-Organisational-Chart-Plugin-With-jQuery-OrgChart.html

Is there someone willing to screen share and teach me how I can install and run it on my pc?

Answer (score -1):

There are several methods

1. Via NPM:
   You'll have to first make that node is installed on your machine. You can check by running `node --version`. Then run `npm install orgchart --save`
   NPM is a repository that keeps tracks of all the javascript packages
2. Via CDN
   You just paste paste the link in the `src` of the `script` tag
3. Bower
   run `bower install orgchart`

Comment: Prabhu, thanks for taking the time. I did step one but I'm not sure how to proceed from there. Is there another way I can contact you? If we share screen it will probably take 15 mins for me to learn all the steps...Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can either Install by using **npm**

npm install orgchart --save

or by using **bower**

bower install orgchart --save

and later require it in app.js or any javascript file you use

apart from it you need to install

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.orgchart.css">
```

and jquery library at the end of the body

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.orgchart.js"></script>
```

Hope it helped!